# Change div colour based on query param ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am attempting to send a query param through the `{{#link-to}}` helper, get the query param in my route and then dynamically change the colour of a div based on the param sent through. I can see I am getting the correct ID but nothing seems to be happening on the page.

Here is my link to helper

```
<li>{{#link-to 'usernotification' (query-params highlightedNotification=activeUserNotification.id)
                            classNames="read-more"}}Read more{{/link-to}}</li>
```

and here is my route

```
export default BaseRoute.extend({
    accountService: Ember.inject.service('account'),
    userNotificationService: Ember.inject.service('usernotification'),

    queryParams: {
        highlightedNotification: {
            refreshModel:true
        }
    },

    beforeModel(params){
        this._super(...arguments);
        Ember.$("#"+params.queryParams.highlightedNotification).attr('style', 'background-color: black !important');
    },

});
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At `beforeModel` hook, route hasn't rendered yet! So the DOM element that you try to modify is not in its place.

You can make it work in some way. For example scheduling to run that code to work at `afterRender` phase by wrapping the code with `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, ()=>{/*your code*/});`. There may some other alternatives.

But this is not ember way of doing. You should pass this data to the corresponding component. The component should decide how it will be displayed.

Further, the name "`highlightedNotification`" maybe wrong. It should be something like: "`selectedNotification`", "`currentNotification`", "`notificationToBeAttentioned`". Let component decide how the attention will be emphasized. "highligting" is just one way to take attention.

Sample [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e3bfebb7f7e177c6114f6b2091fc7c79?openFiles=templates.target-route.hbs%2C) to illustrate the suggested way.